# App crashes when using Application.OpenURL with a local file

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, hololens-emulator

Here's my C# code on Hololens:

`Application.OpenURL("file://"+ Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "file.pdf"));`

This is supposed to open Microsoft Edge with the URL "file://C/Data/.../file.pdf"
But the app crashes when running this code.

It doesn't crash with any other HTTP URLs though.

How can I let Edge know I want to open a local file?

Answer (score 1):

Try path like:

```
file:///C:/
```

not

```
file://C/
```